# Am I correctly interpreting Eq. (4.1) from Erick Weinberg's book, "Classical Solutions in Quantum Field Theory"?

Tags: symmetry, field-theory, group-theory, symmetry-breaking

I have been studying Erick Weinberg's book, "Classical Solutions in Quantum Field Theory", and I am confused about Eq. (4.1) from p. 58.  I believe my issue of confusion is notational, and I think I figured out the resolution.  However, I want to make sure I am interpreting the equation correctly.

This equation appears in Sect. 4.1 of the book, and this section starts on p. 57.  It would not make sense for me to simply quote the equation, and ask what it means.  Therefore, before I quote the equation, I will summarize the text coming before it.

On p. 57, E. Weinberg specifies that he is considering a field theory with scalar fields having a scalar potential $V$.  This potential has degenerate minima which comprise a manifold $\mathcal{M}$.  The scalar potential has a symmetry realized by a group $G$, and the vacuum expectation values of the fields break the symmetry down to a subgroup $H$ of $G$.

If $\phi$ is a set of scalar fields arranged into an $n$-component column vector, then an element
$g$ of $G$ transforms $\phi$ to $D(g)\phi$, where $D(g)$ is an $n \times n$ matrix representation of $g$.  If $\phi_0$ is a vacuum expectation value of $\phi$, and if $h \in H$, then $D(h)\phi_0 = \phi_0$.

I now quote the paragraph preceding Eq. (4.1), along with the equation.  This paragraph starts at the bottom of p. 57, and continues onto p. 58.  My quotation will repeat some of what I specified above.  The paragraph and the equation are as follows.

> "One might then guess that there is a one-to-one correspondence between elements of $G$ and minima of $V$.  This is only true if $G$ is completely broken.  If $G$ is only partially broken, there is an unbroken subgroup $H$ that can be defined by the requirement that it leaves $\phi_0$ invariant; i.e., that $D(h)\phi_0 = \phi_0$ for any element $h$ of $H$.  Consequently, for any given $g \in G$ and $h \in H$, $gh$ and $g$ have the same effect; i.e., $D(gh)\phi_0 = D(g)\phi_0$.  We can therefore define equivalence classes of elements of $G$ by defining two elements $g_1$ and $g_2$ to be equivalent if $g_2 = g_1 h$ for some $h \in H$.  The set of such equivalence classes is the coset space $G/H$.  There is a one-to-one correspondence between these equivalence classes and the minima of $V$, so"
> $$\mathcal{M} = G/H.$$

The above equation is Eq. (4.1).  My point of confusion is that the right side of this equation looks like a quotient group.  A quotient group of the form $A/B$ only is defined if $B$ is a normal subgroup (also called an invariant subgroup or a self-conjugate subgroup) of $A$.  The book did not specify that $H$ was a normal subgroup of $G$, and I do not see a reason that $H$ would have to be a normal subgroup.  The book only specified that $H$ was a subgroup of $G$.

In case my group-theory terminology is different than yours, normal subgroups are defined at

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NormalSubgroup.html

Quotient groups are defined at

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuotientGroup.html

I believe the resolution to this issue is that $G/H$ from Eq. (4.1) does NOT represent a quotient group.  Rather, $G/H$ represents a set of equivalence classes defined in the paragraph above the equation.  The book simply is using the usual notation for a quotient group.

If my terminology is different than yours, then equivalence relations are defined at

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EquivalenceRelation.html

Equivalence classes are defined at

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EquivalenceClass.html

Although it is confusing, it makes some sense for the book to use the notation of a quotient group.  The book defines the elements $g_1$ and $g_2$ of $G$ to be equivalent if $g_2 = g_1 h$, for some $h \in H$.  All elements of the form $g h$ are in the same equivalence class as $g$.  The group $G/H$ defined in the book is the set of all such equivalence classes.  A quotient group is a set of similarly defined equivalence classes.

If $A$ is a group and $B$ is a normal subgroup of $A$, then the quotient group $A/B$ is a mapping of $A$ defined as follows.  All the elements of $B$ are mapped to the identity of $A/B$.  If $a$ is an element of $A$ which is mapped to $a^{\prime}$ in $A/B$, and $b$ is an arbitrary element of $B$, then all elements of the form $ab$ map to $a^{\prime}$.  If $a$ and $c$ are elements of $A$ which respectively map to $a^{\prime}$ and $c^{\prime}$, and if $ac$ maps to $(ac)^{\prime}$, then $a^{\prime}c^{\prime} = (ac)^{\prime}$.

In short, when we define the quotient group $A/B$, we map all elements of the form $ab$ (with $a \in A$ and $b \in B$) from $A$ to the same element in $A/B$.  We could have defined an equivalence relation between each element $a$ and all elements $ab$.  (Again, $a \in A$, and $b \in B$).  A set of equivalent elements would form an equivalence class.  We then could have mapped each equivalence class to a single group element, giving us the group $A/B$.  Thus, the group $A/B$ is a set of equivalence classes, with the equivalence relation being that $ab$ is equivalent to $a$.

As I stated, the quotient group $A/B$ is a set of equivalence classes with each element $a$ from $A$ equivalent to every element $ab$, where $b \in B$.  E. Weinberg's book defines the group $G/H$ to be a set of equivalence classes in which each element $g$ from $G$ is equivalent to every element $gh$, where $h \in H$.  The two definitions almost are the same.  The caveat is that $B$ must be a normal subgroup of $A$ for the quotient group $A/B$ to be defined, but $H$ does not need to be a normal subgroup of $G$.  Rather, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, for which $D(h)\phi_0 = \phi_0$, where $h \in H$.

Because of the similarity of the definition of the equivalence class in the book to the definition of an equivalence class corresponding to a quotient group, it makes sense that the book would use the notation of a quotient group.  In fact, $G/H$ in the book would be a quotient group if $H$ were a normal subgroup of $G$.

I found the same notation used in Vilenkin and Shellard's book, "Cosmic Strings and Other Topological Defects".  So, I believe the notation is standard among physicists working on topological field theory.

I want to make sure I am correctly interpreting Eq. (4.1) from E. Weinberg's book.  I would appreciate input from others.

Comment: Yes, I was confused about this when I read the book too. The point is $G/H$ is a quotient set (i.e. the set of equivalence classes), not a quotient group. All the matters is the fact that $G/H$ is a manifold, it doesn't need to have a group structure.

Comment: Also, it's not like the book is wrong: the "$/$" is just a general notation for quotients in mathematics. The most familiar example to most physicists is the quotient group, but it's far from the only one.

Comment: Thank you.  That clears up my confusion.  After I posted my question, I realized that $G/H$ might not have a group structure.